# IBDesignable: render a UIView in storyboard using IBInspectable an UIImage - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, ibinspectable

I'm creating a `UIView` that allows the user to vote using a classical 5 stars rate system. My code works and everything is fine but I would like to make a preview on the `storyboard` using `IBInspectable` variables.

I really do not know how to achieve that result: I have two `IBInspectable` properties, an `UIImage` and an int. The int tells me how many "stars" I would like to show in the storyboard and the `UIImage` would choose the image used in the app.

> @property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIImage *emptyStarImage;
>
> @property (nonatomic) IBInspectable int numberOfStars;

This is the the thing I'm trying to achieve:

```
float usableWidth = self.frame.size.width - kHorizontalPadding * (self.numberOfStars - 1);
float maxStarSize = MIN(self.frame.size.height - 2 * kVerticalPadding, usableWidth / self.numberOfStars);

for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfStars; i++) {
    
    float xStarPos = kHorizontalPadding * i + (i*maxStarSize);
   
    UIImageView *starView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xStarPos, self.frame.size.height/2, maxStarSize, maxStarSize)];
    starView.image = self.emptyStarImage;
    [self addSubview:starView];
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: You need to add @IBDesignable  in start of view or viewController you are using,

Comment: Thank's Mohammad! I've added it in the .h file but in the wrong area (over the protocol declaration area) :D Your comment made me check my code and I've found my miskake!